# resetting turtlebot odometry in simulation

Tags: navigation, simulation, odometry, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to reset the odometry in simulation of turtlebot.

When I reset the Gazebo world the data published via topic /odom and /robot_pose_ekf/odom remains unchanged. Probably that is because it is not part of the gazebo.

Is there a way I can reset it.

Edit : I am using electric on Ubuntu 11.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60120/resetting-turtlebot-odometry-in-simulation/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2013-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-04-06**:
Please state the ROS distro you are using, e.g. add a tag (fuerte, groovy etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is no. The current plugin does not allow resetting the odom and robot_pose_ekf data.

However, in Gazebo you could just delete the current turtlebot and create a new one.

Please file a ticket on Github for this missing feature: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues

Or even better, implement the necessary changes and make a pull request! :-)

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-04-06**:
Ok, thanks

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-04-12**:
Just a thought, in navigation stack robot is localized in the map. So that must be constantly updating odom of it. How is that done?